# scipy install via macports fail after selfupdate

Tags: scipy, macports

I am having some trouble getting py27-scipy to build & install after upgrading to the latest version of macports (MacPorts base version 2.0.3 installed).

The exact build error is:-

```
:info:build In file included from scipy/integrate/_quadpackmodule.c:6:
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h:54: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h:55: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h:56: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h:57: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h:58: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h:59: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h:60: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h: In function 'quad_function':
:info:build scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h:74: warning: unused variable 'nb'
:info:build scipy/integrate/_quadpackmodule.c: At top level:
:info:build /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:391: warning: 'simple_capsule_dtor' defined but not used
:info:build /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.4 -Wall -Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/scipy/integrate/_quadpackmodule.o -L/opt/local/lib/gcc44/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10/4.4.6 -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7 -lquadpack -llinpack_lite -lmach -lgfortran -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/scipy/integrate/_quadpack.so
:info:build building 'scipy.integrate._odepack' extension
:info:build compiling C sources
:info:build C compiler: /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
:info:build 
:info:build compile options: '-DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c'
:info:build extra options: '-faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers'
:info:build gcc-mp-4.4: scipy/integrate/_odepackmodule.c
:info:build cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-faltivec"
:info:build cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-faltivec"
:info:build error: Command "/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c scipy/integrate/_odepackmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/scipy/integrate/_odepackmodule.o -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
:info:build shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_python_py-scipy/py27-scipy/work/scipy-0.9.0" && /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 setup.py --no-user-cfg config_fc --fcompiler gnu95 --f77exec /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.4 --f90exec /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.4 config --cc /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 --include-dirs /opt/local/include --library-dirs /opt/local/lib build " returned error 1
:error:build Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:build Backtrace: shell command failed (see log for details)
while executing
"command_exec build"
(procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for py27-scipy): org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:build Log for py27-scipy is at: /opt/local/var/macports 
/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_python_py-scipy/py27-scipy/main.log
```

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you did to resolve it? I looked at the ticket you referenced and rebuilt gcc44 with the compiler flag suggested, but still have the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. In my case it was caused by an old dev build of numpy on my systems that was confusing the build process. Removing the referenced .egg entirely worked for me. See the MacPorts ticket:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31833

Answer (score 0):

This problem was a result of gfortran/gcc44 not compiling properly because I was using Lion/XCode 4.2.

Reference macports ticket that was resolved - https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31604